# Multiline powershell in Makefile

Tags: powershell, makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile for my Windows setup (using Powershell instead of Bash), and I'm trying to enter mutiline command in it.

For example:

```
SHELL := pwsh.exe
.SHELLFLAGS := -Command

...

clean-all: 
    @if ( Test-Path ${OUTPUT_FOLDER} ) {                       ` \
        (Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path "${OUTPUT_FOLDER}") ` \
    }
```

Multiline command in Poweshell can be written by using `` ` `` symbol, multiline script in Makefile can be written by using `\`. It seems to be conflict between them, because I tried to use `\n`, `` ` ``, `` ` \ ``, `\` as end of line, but nothing works.

I got an error like: `Unexpected token '\' in expression or statement.` on the line `` (Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path "${OUTPUT_FOLDER}") ` \ ``

Answer (score 0):

The `\` is a special character in PS, and if you require it, you need to properly escape it.

For Example:

```
'Hello\Hi' -replace '.*\'
# Results
<#
The regular expression pattern .*\ is not valid.
At line:1 char:1
+ "Hello\Hi" -replace '.*\'
#>

'Hello\Hi' -replace '.*\\'
# Results
<#
Hi
#>
```

Anyway, what happens is you do it this way? I have nothing to run with makefile, so, I cannot test this.

```
SHELL := pwsh.exe
.SHELLFLAGS := -Command

...

clean-all: 
    @if ( Test-Path ${OUTPUT_FOLDER} ) {                       ` \ `
        (Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path "${OUTPUT_FOLDER}") ` \
    }
```

Comment: That doesnt work, unfortunately